# How can I know if phone is already infected?

Tags: malware, android, mobile, virus, backdoor

Last year, my friend who is learning hacking for nearly 3 years hacked my phone using social engineering by installing some malware in my phone. (After researching on Google, I think it might be a reverse meterpreter)

As soon as I realized that my phone has infected after one hour since malware was installed, I scanned my phone with Avast anti-virus program and found that malware and deleted it.

After about one month, some strange things were happened without my knowledge. First of all, there was a message **which I didn't send** in my phone. The contents of the message contained some codes. After I saw it, I reset my phone immediately. Second thing is that some of my messages in Messenger were automatically seen even before I didn't read them. I checked the devices from **Where You're Logged In** in Facebook Settings but there were no unknown devices listed there. **Two-Factor Authentication** is turned on. So I presume my Facebook account is not hacked. (I already have some security knowledge and I haven't never clicked any suspicious links yet). I think it happened from my phone. There were also some strange things.

- The question is how can I know that my phone is hacked? How do I know if it has backdoors?

Btw my phone is running android 11. I wanna ask this because even I reset my phone and scanned with anti-virus programs (for social accounts I changed passwords), messages on Messenger were still seen automatically and sometimes some apps are automatically closed like **camera** app when I am taking photos with tripod.

- After my phone was hacked by my friend (I deleted that malware), can he still hack my phone? Did he know my MAC or IP addresses?
- The last question is once my phone is hacked, can malware spread thru WiFi and infect other devices? (In my case it is a Windows 10 laptop)

Comment: If it's running stock ROM and bootloader is locked, your device will return to safe state after factory reset.

Comment: @defalt When I bought my phone, Android version is 9. Now it is 11. Can I say it's running stock ROM?

Comment: It seems to be running stock. You should still verify **About phone** of your device and also check if the bootloader is locked.

Comment: @dafalt Thanks man I checked my phone's build number and model number. It's running stock ROM and bootloader is locked in developer options. So I will reset my phone.

Comment: Also just a small advice to be more safe, change all passwords and make sure they differ from each other, just in case your friend or somebody else got them.

Comment: @mrSotirow I usually change my passwords (especially Facebook account) once a month. But it didn't help. Some messages in Messenger were still seen automatically. My phone is not rooted. Can hacker get root privileges once he hack non-rooted phone?

Comment: @Enthalpy127 everything is possible as there may be vulnerabilities that are not known but maybe found by somebody else. If you have a chance end all sessions (even yours) in facebook and messanger, maybe this meterpreter somehow persists even after factory reset and/or the meterpreter binary has a backdoor and not only your friend but maybe somebody else has access to your phone too.

Comment: Verify bootloader status using fastboot, not by developer options. Refer to forums of your device.

Comment: @defalt To use fastboot, I need pc. Right now I'm away from home. I'll check it when I arrive at my home. Now I just wanna know that can malware spread to my laptop. If so, I also need to check my pc.

Comment: @mrSotirow If so, what should I do? Should I flash firmware and reset my phone? I am so disappointed.

Comment: @Enthalpy127 Well maybe see phone service, they could help you ?

Comment: @defalt It takes me a day to verify bootloader status with fastboot. When I use fastboot tool (Minimal ADB and Fastboot), my phone can't enter fastboot mode. And I asked why it happens in some forums and some people said my Oppo F11 has non-unlockable bootloader by default and fastboot mode is intentionally blocked. It will be very hard to root my phone. Although I still haven't known bootloader status, I think I can say my bootloader is locked. Are you sure all viruses will be gone after factory reset? In other words, can malware exist on `/boot` or `/system` partition on non-rooted phone?

Comment: Unless it's a highly intrusive malware, it's unlikely it can have persistence after factory reset.

Comment: In that case, re-flashing the ROM might solve the problem I think.